# Labels from multiple series overlap

Tags: highcharts, label, padding, series, overlap

I have a container within which multiple series are displayed; I'm getting the data for the series from somewhere out of my reach. Each series has a label attached to it's last value.

The problem is that when the values from several series are close to each other, the labels overlap each other. I tried a couple of things which didn't work; I realize now the problem was I tried to adjust the settings of the individual series while what I need should somehow apply to combinations of series. I had no luck trying to find out how to get what I need.

Here's my fiddle. You can see there how the label "70" completely overlaps label "71" so the latter is not visible at all. If I remove the "70" label from the chart, "71" can be seen.

```
 `http://jsfiddle.net/oybn2kax/8/`
```

Is there anything that can be done so that the labels are displayed in a way for both of them to be visible even if the values are close to each other?

Thanks a lot for your help and have a good time!

Comment: http://r-man.cz/Download/03%20Growduino/Highcharts.JPG

Comment: I can see that your issue attached in the image is more complicated than this simple example in the question. For these two series from your jsfiddle, you can manually set the second y position of the label: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zkom3qcd/, but according to your image I am considering that using the `series-label` might be a good idea - this feature has built logic to avoid overlapping - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.label